# windows workflow 4 workflow stalls

Tags: iis, workflow-foundation-4

I have a windows workflow that is stalling.  By stalling I mean a workflow, hosted in iis, goes past the pending timer without it continuing to the next step.  If I create another workflow it will kick start the workflow engine again, but I don't really want to create a workflow to do just that.

The workflow is intended to be run over the course of 30 days.  We are testing it now and to test it I wrote some code to pull config file values in for simulation-days.  Right now 5 minutes is equal to 1 day and all the logic is based on Timespans calculated from the simulation-days.  Looking at the InstancesTable I see that it sets the PendingTimer correctly (and I know the PendingTimer is not the same timezone as me).  There is no exception in the SuspensionExceptionName or SuspensionReason columns, nor anything in the eventlog of the server.

So what can I do to troubleshoot or isolate what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like IIS is recycling the AppDomain and the WorkflowServiceHost is not reloaded because there is no external request coming in. If you are using Windows Server AppFabric you can configure it to restart the AppDomain and the WorkflowServiceHost right away. Otherwise you can request the WSDL from the workflow service to "manually" load the WorkflowServiceHost.

Comment: Looks like that will do what I need it to.  Thanks.

Comment: If the service is publicly available you can use something like http://www.uptimerobot.com/ to automatically request the WSDL for you. If it is internal writing some Windows Service to do this is a trivial exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do that.  Something is wrong - the AppFabric Workflow Management Service should be waking up your workflows with Durable Timers.

Check the Windows Event log to see if you are getting errors from that service.

Comment: This server doesn't have AppFabric nor can it be installed, too old.